# Create dataframe from excel by reading sheet names python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel workbook with 4 worksheets with different names. I want to read them into pandas dataframe only if they are called in the variable `sheet_names`. For example, the entire workbook's sheet names can be `['banana','orange','apple','grape']`. Each sheet has 5 columns that I want to read into Python.

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_names =['grapes','orange'] #sheet_names is what I control... it can contain any number of sheets between 1 to 4.

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Ken\\Desktop\\Df.xlsx')

df = []

for x in sheet_names:
    df.append(xlsx.parse(sheetname=x,index_col=0,parse_cols='B:F'))
```

However the code returns a list with len = 2.

The desired output is a dataframe with 10 columns. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call of `xlsx.parse()` returns a DataFrame, which you are appending to the `df` **list**. So in your code `df` is a list of DFs. If you want to merge selected sheets you can use [pd.concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
df = pd.concat([xlsx.parse(sheetname=x,index_col=0,parse_cols='B:F') for x in sheet_names],
               axis=1,
               ignore_index=True)
```

PS you may want to preserver original indexes - in this case change `ignore_index=True` to `ignore_index=False`